Unable to Access Custom Route in OpenCart
I've created a new controller in my OpenCart installation but cannot access it through the expected URL. Instead, I get the standard "Page not found" error.
File Structure:
Controller file path
catalog/controller/custom/simplejson.php
Controller Code (simplejson.php):
<?php
class ControllerCustomSimplejson extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $data = array('message' => 'This is a test JSON response');
        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($data));
    }
}


Expected Behavior: When accessing the URL http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=custom/simplejson, I expect to see a JSON response with the message "This is a test JSON response".

Is your Opencart installation in opencart directory? If not, then ignore it, use http://localhost/index.php?route=custom/simplejson URL, it must work.

it is working in live environment
be sure that you visit the link
http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=custom/simplejson
without any .PHP extension at the end
